# How do i make button that fade between color E.g purple to blue in html

Tags: html, css, button, colors

I don't know how to make a button that begin with blue from the right and the turns more purple to the left in HTML and CSS

```
  <button style="background-color: purple">Shop</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at [linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `linear-gradient` option of the css background property to do this. See below and tweak the colors to your needs:

```css
.blue-purple-gradient{
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn,purple, blue);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class='blue-purple-gradient'>Shop</button>
```